# Find and replace regex within text file (mac addresses)

Tags: python, python-3.x

This has been asked other places, but no joy when trying those solutions.  I am trying to search and replace using open(file) instead of file input.  Reason is I am printing a "x of y completed" message as it works (fileinput puts that in the file and not to terminal).  My test file is 100 mac addresses separated by new lines.

All I would like to do is find the regex matching a mac address and replace it with "MAC ADDRESS WAS HERE".  Below is what I have and it is only putting the replace string once at bottom of file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import getopt
import re
import socket
import os
import fileinput
import time

file = sys.argv[1]

regmac = re.compile("^(([a-fA-F0-9]{2}-){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2}|([a-fA-F0-9]{2}:){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2}|([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\.){2}[0-9A-Fa-f]{4})?$")
regmac1 = "^(([a-fA-F0-9]{2}-){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2}|([a-fA-F0-9]{2}:){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2}|([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\.){2}[0-9A-Fa-f]{4})?$"
regv4 = re.compile(r'^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$')
regv41 = '^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$'

menu = {}
menu['1']="MAC"
menu['2']="IPV4"
menu['3']="IPV6"
menu['4']="STRING"
menu['5']="EXIT"

while True:
    options=menu.keys()
    sorted(options)
    for entry in options:
        print(entry, menu[entry])

    selection = input("Please Select:")
    if selection == '1':
        print("MAC chosen...")
        id = str('mac')
        break
    elif selection == '2':
        print("IPV4 chosen")
        id = str('ipv4')
        break
    elif selection == '3':
        print("IPV6 chosen")
        id = str('ipv6')
        break
    elif selection == '4':
        print("String chosen")
        id = str('string')
        break
    elif selection == '5':
        print("Exiting...")
        exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid selection!")

macmatch = 0
total = 0

while id == 'mac': 
    with open(file, 'r') as i:
        for line in i.read().split('\n'):
            matches = regmac.findall(line)
            macmatch += 1
        print("I found",macmatch,"MAC addresses")
        print("Filtering found MAC addresses")
    i.close()

    with open(file, 'r+') as i:
        text = i.readlines()
        text = re.sub(regmac, "MAC ADDRESS WAS HERE", line)
        i.write(text)
```

The above will put "MAC ADDRESS WAS HERE", at the end of the last line while not replacing any MAC addresses.
I am fundamentally missing something.  If someone would please point me in right direction that would be great!

caveat, I have this working via fileinput, but cannot display progress from it, so trying using above.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All, I figured it out.  Posting working code just in case someone happens upon this post.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#Rewriting Sanitizer script from bash
#Import Modules, trying to not download any additional packages.  Using regex to make this python2 compatible (does not have ipaddress module).

import sys
import getopt
import re
import socket
import os
import fileinput
import time

#Usage Statement sanitize.py /path/to/file, add help statement
#Test against calling entire directories, * usage

#Variables
file = sys.argv[1]
regmac = re.compile("^(([a-fA-F0-9]{2}-){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2}|([a-fA-F0-9]{2}:){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2}|([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\.){2}[0-9A-Fa-f]{4})?$")
regmac1 = "^(([a-fA-F0-9]{2}-){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2}|([a-fA-F0-9]{2}:){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2}|([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\.){2}[0-9A-Fa-f]{4})?$"
regv4 = re.compile(r'^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$')
regv41 = '^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$'

#Functions

menu = {}
menu['1']="MAC"
menu['2']="IPV4"
menu['3']="IPV6"
menu['4']="STRING"
menu['5']="EXIT"

while True:
    options=menu.keys()
    sorted(options)
    for entry in options:
        print(entry, menu[entry])

    selection = input("Please Select:")
    if selection == '1':
        print("MAC chosen...")
        id = str('mac')
        break
    elif selection == '2':
        print("IPV4 chosen")
        id = str('ipv4')
        break
    elif selection == '3':
        print("IPV6 chosen")
        id = str('ipv6')
        break
    elif selection == '4':
        print("String chosen")
        id = str('string')
        break
    elif selection == '5':
        print("Exiting...")
        exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid selection!")

macmatch = 0
total = 0

while id == 'mac': 
    with open(file, 'r') as i:
        for line in i.read().split('\n'):
            matches = regmac.findall(line)
            macmatch += 1
        print("I found",macmatch,"MAC addresses")
        print("Filtering found MAC addresses")
    i.close()

    with open(file, 'r') as i:
        lines = i.readlines()
        
    with open(file, 'w') as i:
        for line in lines:
                line = re.sub(regmac, "MAC ADDRESS WAS HERE", line)
                i.write(line)
        i.close()
    break
```

The above overwrites the regex match (found MAC address) with "MAC ADDRESS WAS HERE". Hopefully this helps someone.  Any suggestions to make this more efficient or another way to accomplish are welcomed.  Will mark as answer once i am able to, 2days.